# "ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types" when specifying enum underlying type

Tags: c++, clang

Given the program:

```
enum E : int
{
    A, B, C
};
```

`g++ -c test.cpp` works just fine. However, `clang++ -c test.cpp` gives the following errors:

```
test.cpp:1:6: error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types
enum E : int
     ^
test.cpp:1:8: error: expected unqualified-id
enum E : int
       ^
2 errors generated.
```

These error messages don't make any sense to me. I don't see any forward references here.

Comment: FWIW, GCC now (as of 5 or 6) compiles with `‑std=c++14` as the default, while Clang still uses `‑std=c++98` AFAIK.

Comment: I think it would help if you included compiler versions and options.

Comment: Compiler versions (plus full shell transcript for people suggesting that my actual source code does not correspond to the one in the question): https://dump.thecybershadow.net/6bf06811a8f77fce574017622d1dd8e7/21%3A51%3A18-upload.txt

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question to me, it is not a typographical error, and it is not a question seeking debugging help that doesn't include the code and error message.

Comment: didn't vote, but using `-std=c++11` is the first thing to try when you use a C++11 feature and get strange error messages

Comment: Didn't know at the time that it was a C++11 feature. The syntax is not new - the MS compilers have supported this syntax since at least VS2005.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Linked question is actually about forward declarations of an enum. This question is NOT about forward declarations of an enum - the error message implies it, but the situation and underlying cause are different.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Specifying the underlying type for an enum is a C++11 language feature. To get the code to compile, you must add the switch `-std=c++11`. This works for both GCC and Clang.

For enums in C++03, the underlying integral type is implementation-defined, unless the values of the enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. (However, Microsoft's compiler has allowed specifying the underlying type of an enum as a proprietary extension since VS 2005.)

Comment: You're right:  if  you compile with option -std=c++11 is works ([online demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:'enum+E+:+int%0A%7B%0A++++A,+B,+C%0A%7D%3B')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)).  With gcc older than 6 give you an explicit warning.  With gcc 6 no nead for the std flag.

Comment: @Christophe: Which is to say: with gcc 6, they (finally) changed it to compile C++11 by default, and require a switch to conform with older standards.